# How to do service request in background when app receives push notification iOS

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, background-process

I want to do a service request in background when app receives push notification. I am able to get notifications in foreground and background, in foreground I am using below method to do the service request,

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    completionHandler([.alert,.sound])
}
```

But in the background I am not getting how to do service request, the above method is not calling when app in background. How can I do this?

Comment: https://samwize.com/2015/08/07/how-to-handle-remote-notification-with-background-mode-enabled/

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable background mode for push notifications in the capabilities tab
2. Implement the didReceiveRemoteNotification method and add your service request code there.
3. Make sure the notification payload has "content-available": 1 for the silent push notification.

   Thats it.